# Type checks fail when trying to migrate from postgresql 10 to postgresql 12

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

in our company we are using Django 2.2 with Postgresql 10 on a RDS instance. We need to upgrade the DB to Postgresql 12 by the beginning of april, so we are doing some tests to try to do it with the less down time possible.

While doing that, we have created a exact replica of our production database (with version 10) and now we want to replicate the data in another database (with the same resources) but running version 12.

For that, we have created in AWS a Database Migration Task. This task just replicates the data (like a master slave) from one database to the other. However, we are facing the following problem:

[image]

As you can see, we have one type that is not supported `_varchar` and another two with a warning: `float8` and `geometry` (not listed in the screenshot).

Not sure if it's useful, but here is the python code from the ORM generating the table affected by that error:

```python
class AppointmentLogHistory(models.Model):
    stored_image_url = ArrayField(models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=512, null=True), null=True)
    stored_thumbnail_url = ArrayField(models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=512, null=True), null=True)
```

Any idea how to solve that error and the warnings? Or any tips for doing the database migration? We are pretty unexperienced in this kind of migration, so we want to avoid any surprises.

Comment: The error is not from django, is from the replication process in RDS.

Comment: I see. Perhaps Amazon can tell you more. Anyway, I'll retract my close vote.